# java.io.FileNotFoundException in Jmeter even if file is in bin folder itself

Tags: csv, exception, jmeter, filepath, filenotfoundexception

java.io.FileNotFoundException in Jmeter even if file is in bin folder itself

I have created a file in jmeter/bin Folder and then used it in Jmeter script without any path (only file name as it is already in bin folder)
Still I am getting error as java.io.FileNotFoundException[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filename path could be relative (to your .jmx file) or absolute (/home/username...).

Check your path for trailing spaces - jmeter doesnt know how to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually relative path in [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) (not in distributed test) is relative to **test plan** and not jmeter execution directory:

> Filename Name of the file to be read. Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan.

You can also use absolute path or move your CSV file to same directory of your JMX files.